# Azure API Management - Returning A PDF - Policy?

Tags: azure-api-management

Is it possible to return a pdf or file stream over the API Management?

In our API we can, but after we add it to the API Management, the call now returns garbled characters.

Is there a policy we can use so that the API would return a file?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no issue returning any content type (including PDFs) across API Management.  It is possible that we Gzip the result for you if the client says that it accepts Gzip encoding.

There should be no need to add any policies to enable this.  See if your client sends an Accept-Encoding header. If so, remove it and try the request again.